# Maintain state upon return to app on launcher apps :: Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

I created an Android launcher app that has Home button functionality that will take you out of the launcher and to the standard Android home screen. I do this with the following code snipet:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

The issue I am running into is that when the user re-launches the launcher app it starts from the beginning. I am not returned back to the same Activity I launched from. My suspicion is that this is because the app is a launcher, so it does not behave the same as normal app whose Activity goes into the background and can be returned back to. The behavior, instead, is that it finishes all the activities from the stack task.

Any suggestions for preventing or working around this?

For those asking about manifest, these are the steps for creating a launcher

1) I added the following attribute to activity

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

2) I added the following categories to intent filter

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

Lastly, I have created a demo that demonstrates the issue I am describing. Here: [www.mediafire.com/download/qu5nfzoaj8cqjtu/LauncherDemo.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/download/qu5nfzoaj8cqjtu/LauncherDemo.zip)

Comment: Post the manifest for your launcher app

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Are you sure you aren't calling `finish()` on your launcher when you go back to the Android HOME screen?

Comment: You can use `adb shell dumpsys activity` to see all the active tasks and their activities. perhaps you can do this before you return to the Android HOME screen and then again after you return to Android HOME screen and see what the state of your launcher task is.

Comment: Yes, I am positive. I believe it is because it is a launcher, that this is the behavior. As normal app, Activity just goes into onPause() and I can return back.

Comment: Good suggestion, I will look into this. +1 for response. Thank you

Comment: A launcher isn't special in that regard. Your launcher will also just pause and go to the background when you return to Android HOME screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61942/discussion-between-portfoliobuilder-and-david-wasser).

Comment: Did you get anywhere? I didn't get any email from you as promised

Comment: David, I posted the demo in my question for you. I still have no solution for this.

Comment: Sorry, just had a chance to look at it. You are right that your task is being stripped. The launcher task does go to the background intact (with the other activity on top). However, when Android restarts the launcher, it clears the task. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your demo. Unfortunately this can't work.

When Android starts a LAUNCHER, it sets the following Intent flag:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
```

This causes the task to be stripped down to the root activity. You don't have any control over the Intent flags that are set when your LAUNCHER activity is started, so you cannot prevent this from happening.

In general, LAUNCHER activities have `launchMode="singleInstance"`. This means that when a LAUNCHER starts an Activity, that Activity ends up in another task. The LAUNCHER activity is always in a task all by itself. This is so that you can always bring the LAUNCHER activity to the foreground (because it has no other activities in its task).

You probably need to rethink your architecture. Sorry.

Comment: Aye, this is what I suspected. Thanks for the help!